# Пепперони/пеперони

Tags: орфография

Правда, что корректно писать и *пепперони* и *пеперони*?

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%2C+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&soothing=3

Comment: Перед второй _и_ запятая .

Comment: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112

Comment: Ссылаться в тексте вопроса на источник информации нормально, но, не раскрывая причины, ограничиваться лишь ссылкой неправильно. Ваши проблемы не следует целиком перекладывать на плечи других.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Какой пункт?

Comment: Второй абзац после 26-го пункта.

Comment: Минусую, так как нет оснований для игнорирования запятой между "и,.. и", так как нет фразеологизации.

Comment: Вниз смотрите на то, что Sharon написала-с!

Comment: Основания есть!

Comment: Основания для не постановки запятой - фразеологизация. Тут фразеологизации нет, а значит и оснований нет. Запятая нужна. Шарон ничего про фразеологизацию не писала, она вообще упустила из виду, что коты не ставят запятых там, где нужны-с.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***пеперони.***

[**Орфографический словарь:**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8&all=x)   пеперони, нескл., м. и с.

Более распространенной является запись ***пепперони***.

**[Почему пепперони так назвали?](https://instafood.com.ua/pitstsa-pepperoni-chto-eto-istoriya-sozdaniya-originalnogo-blyuda)**

**Пепперони** (***peperoni***) — в переводе с итальянского означает маленький стручковый красный перчик. Острый до безобразия. Именно от него и растут ноги названия нашей пиццы. Сначала так называли перчики, потом стали называть твердую острую колбасу, изготавливаемую из смеси говядины и свинины, обладающую выраженным своеобразным вкусом.

Трудно **объяснить** популярность такого названия.

Comment: То есть как правильно писать? Он популярен потому, что в других языках две *п*.

Comment: Согласно словарю РАН.  В итальянском языке peperoni.

Comment: Нужна запятая или нет?

Comment: А где из словаря ссылка?

Comment: You didn't notice the link, sir)

Comment: The comma is not needed (the union И ... И denotes a close connection of words).

Comment: Шарон, не верно, https://www.etymonline.com/word/pepperoni от пеппер - перец, так что с двумя п.

Comment: А мы по-итальянски пишем.  Смотрите словарь РАН,  и больше ничего не смотрите))

Comment: Проблема, что у итальянцев нет пеперони, потому что пеперони - это перец, а не салями с перцем. https://www.thoughtco.com/you-say-pepperoni-3972377

Comment: В РАН только пеперони  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=пеперонни&all=x

Comment: Запятая не нужна.

Comment: Совсем не нужна? А кому и почему? И какая запятая?